# Eigenvalue density expansion in random matrices

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices

First, some background and context. Curently I am studying the basics of "random matrices" and their large N expansion. At large $N$ I know that the eigenvalues condense in what is called the Wigner semicircle. I see this function as the first term in a sort of asymptotic expansion. In fact I found this expansion
$$\rho(x)=\sum^\infty_{g=0}N^{-2g}\rho^{(g)}(x)+non-perturbative$$
it is equation (1.80) in

> Random matrices. Bertrand Eynard, Taro Kimura, Sylvain Ribault [arXiv:1510.04430](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.04430v1).

That only even powers of $1/N$
appear in the perturbative terms is a mistery for me.

How we can prove that expansion? Can you give some references?

Comment: If you are a beginner, a more accessible introduction to random matrices can be found in this short book: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07903
and references therein

Answer (score 2):

In general the $1/N$ expansion does actually contain all powers, for example, in the Gaussian orthogonal ensemble (GOE, real symmetric matrices) the first two terms are

$$\rho(x)=\frac{2N}{\pi x_c^2}\sqrt{x_c^2-x^2}+\tfrac{1}{4}\delta(x-x_c)+\tfrac{1}{4}\delta(x+x_c)-\frac{1}{2\pi}(x_c^2-x^2)^{-1/2}+{\cal O}(N^{-1}),$$

where the order $N$ term is the Wigner semicircle, supported in $(-x_c,x_c)$.

For symplectic matrices (GSE) the expansion is similar, it is only for complex matrices (GUE) that the even powers of $1/N$ vanish.

When you do the $1/N$ expansion of $\rho(x)=\langle \sum_{i=1}^N\delta(x-x_n)\rangle$ for an eigenvalue distribution of the general form 
$$P(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_N)=\prod_{i<j}|x_i-x_j|^\beta\prod_k f(x_k),$$
you find that the order $N^0$ term is proportional to $2-\beta$ irrespective of the choice of $f(x)$. (So this is not something special for the Gaussian distribution.) In the GUE one has $\beta=2$, hence this term vanishes.

I don't know of an intuitive answer for this fact that does not require a calculation, but there may well be one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am solving the integral in $\langle \sum_{i=1}^N\delta(x-x_n)\rangle$ but I cannot find that the odd powers are proportional to $2-\beta$.

Comment: what is your result for the order $N^{0}$ term? it should be $(2-\beta)(4\beta)^{-1}[\delta(x-x_c)+\delta(x+x_c)]$; do note that the "odd-even" names refer to the rescaled density --- in this answer I am not rescaling, so the powers in the expansion that are missing are the "even" powers

Comment: I cannot see any deltas, I have integrated all them. And I dont know how to get and $1/N$ expansion, son I dont know what the $N^0$ term is. Is this in some paper or book?

Comment: here is a reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0508031